# balls in bins with finite capacity and overflow: mean ball overflow

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins, polya-urn-model

Say you have $M$ bins and $N$ balls, and each bin can only be filled with $C$ balls. At step zero, all bins are empty. Then at each step, one of the $M$ bins is chosen with equal probability, and a ball is "dropped" onto it. If the bin is filled with less than $C$ balls, its ball count is increased by 1. If it is filled with $C$ balls, the ball falls to the floor. After $N$ steps (i.e. all balls are used), what is the mean number of balls on the floor?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839891/expected-total-number-of-balls-in-all-bins-after-throwing-balls-uniformly-random?rq=1) stack exchange question is nearly the same, but the answer is not explained, appears to not be general, and debated in a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $A_i$ as the number of balls assigned (randomly) to bin $i$. The residual of each bin $i$ overflowing on the floor is given by

$$R_i=\max ( A_i-C, 0 ).$$

Considering that each $A_i$ follows the binomial distribution with parameters $n=N$ and $p=1/M$, the expectation of $R_i$ is given by

$$\mathbb{E}(R_i)=\sum_{i=C+1}^N  (i-C){N \choose i } \ \left (\frac{1}{M}\right ) ^i \left (\frac{M-1}{M}\right )^{N-i}.$$

Considering $R=\sum_{i=1}^M R_i$ and that $\mathbb{E}(U+V)=\mathbb{E}(U)+\mathbb{E}(V)$ whenever both $\mathbb{E}(U)$ and $\mathbb{E}(V)$ are finite (i.e., $U \text{ and } V \in L_1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$; $U$ and $V$ can be dependent), the expectation of all the residuals can be obtained as follows:

$$\mathbb{E}(R)=\sum_{i=1}^M \mathbb{E}(R_i)=M \times \mathbb{E}(R_1)=\left (\frac{1}{M} \right )^{N-1} \sum_{i=C+1}^N  (i-C){N \choose i }(M-1)^{N-i}. $$

This can be simplified to

$$\mathbb{E}(R)={\left (\frac{1}{M} \right )^{N-1}} \left (  N \sum_{j=C}^{N-1}  {N-1 \choose j }(M-1)^{N-1-j}- C \sum_{i=C+1}^N  {N \choose i }(M-1)^{N-i} \right ) $$

or based on the CDFs of two binomial random variables:

$$\mathbb{E}(R)=M \left [ C\, \mathbb{P}\left (W(N) \le C\right ) - N\,  \mathbb{P}\left (W(N-1)\le C-1\right ) +N-C \right ] $$

with $W(N) \sim \text{Binomial}(N,1/M)$ and $W(N-1) \sim \text{Binomial}(N-1,1/M)$. You can see that the expectation becomes zero for $C=N$.

The latter can be used to compute the expectation in R or python, or to approximate the expectation using CLT when $N$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: I’m confused about the step where all of the expectations are added together. Are we allowed so do that even though the Ai’s are not independent and sum to N?

Comment: @user3433489 I just clarified the answer. 

Note that we always have $\mathbb{E}(U+V)=\mathbb{E}(U)+\mathbb{E}(V)$ whenever both $\mathbb{E}(U)$ and $\mathbb{E}(V)$ are finite ($U$ and $V$ can be dependent). In fact, the expectation is a linear operator on the space of random variables with finite means. But it is not the case for $\mathbb{E}(UV)=\mathbb{E}(U)\mathbb{E}(V)$ or $\text{var}(U+V)=\text{var}(U)+\text{var}(V)$, which generally hold for independent $U$ and $V $.

Comment: Thank you for explaining!